# Filter function in python

Tags: python

I am having 1 list "name_list".

```
name_list=['Name:Bill,Age:28,Height:6.1', 'Name:Dona,Age:23,Height:6.1','Name:Bill,Age:22,Height:6.1', 'Name:Shelly,Age:24,Height:7']
```

1) I want to sort the list with common datas. For example the output should come like this:

```
out=['Name:Bill,Age:28,Height:6.1', 'Name:Bill,Age:22,Height:6.1']
```

2) I want to sort the list with Max. Age. For example If I want to check out who is having max age output should come like this.

```
out=['Name:Bill,Age:28,Height:6.1']
```

This is what I have done till now:

```
name_list=['Name:Bill,Age:28,Height:6.1', 'Name:Dona,Age:23,Height:6.1','Name:Bill,Age:22,Height:6.1', 'Name:Shelly,Age:24,Height:7'] 


out = filter(lambda x:'Name:Bill' in x and 'Height:6.1' in x,list)
```

Comment: And what `attributes` are included in your `common datas`?

Comment: For what user input you want the output as `: 'Name:Bill,Age:28,Height:6.1', 'Name:Bill,Age:22,Height:6.1'` ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the list to a structure that is easier to process, for example:

```
people = [
    dict(x.split(':') for x in y.split(','))
    for y in name_list
]
```

This gives you something like:

```
[{'Age': '28', 'Name': 'Bill', 'Height': '6.1'}, 
 {'Age': '23', 'Name': 'Dona', 'Height': '6.1'}, 
 {'Age': '22', 'Name': 'Bill', 'Height': '6.1'}, 
 {'Age': '24', 'Name': 'Shelly', 'Height': '7'}]
```

Iterate over this list and pick whatever attributes you need. For example, to find the oldest person:

```
oldest = max(people, key=lambda x: x['Age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would organize the data using `collections.namedtuple`:

```
In [41]: from collections import namedtuple
         person = namedtuple('person','name age height')

In [42]: persons=[person(*(i.split(':')[1] for i in n.split(','))) 
                                               for n in name_list]

In [43]: max(persons,key=lambda x:x.age)
Out[43]: person(name='Bill', age='28', height='6.1')

In [44]: max(persons,key=lambda x:x.height)
Out[44]: person(name='Shelly', age='24', height='7')

In [45]: max(persons,key=lambda x:x.height).name
Out[45]: 'Shelly'
In [46]: persons
Out[46]: 
[person(name='Bill', age='28', height='6.1'),
 person(name='Dona', age='23', height='6.1'),
 person(name='Bill', age='22', height='6.1'),
 person(name='Shelly', age='24', height='7')]
```